# What are some issues with ETN Commodities Indexes?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, commodities, etn

I am thinking of buying, two ETNs in Commodities Metals (Copper, Nickel). I am curious of risk factors for these.

1. Besides Barclays Bank going bankrupt during a market crash with unsecured ETN debts, and
2. slight difference between spot price due to contago/backwardization,

Is there anything else I should be aware of ?

I see lot of articles on ETNs and risks, however in the resource articles listed, they are totally different products related to Mortgage, and redemptions etc.

Just curious if anyone is familiar with these products. Currently reading through the 200 page prospectus.

```
JJN - iPath Series B Bloomberg Nickel Subindex Total ReturnSM ETN
```

https://www.ipathetn.com/US/16/en/instruments.app#/details/341631

or

```
JJC - iPath® Series B Bloomberg Copper Subindex Total ReturnSM ETN
```

https://www.ipathetn.com/US/16/en/instruments.app#/details/341625

**Resource articles:**

https://www.forbes.com/sites/rickferri/2012/07/12/investors-warned-about-etn-risks/

https://www.schwab.com/resource-center/insights/content/exchange-traded-notes-the-facts-and-the-risks

Comment: Welcome new user, Just curious, why wouldn't one simply trade copper futures?  They are easily and instantly accessible on all brokers.  What is the actual advantage really? :O

Comment: Well, I don't have the money for copper futures, they are pretty large I think trade $36000 in full, If I decided not to leverage around 12000* 3 = $36000, Since I don't want to leverage, I like to invest in full : )  https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/emini-copper_contract_specifications.html

Comment: gotchya, that makes perfect sense.  it looks like there's a mini, but it's only 1/2 size it seems?